# Moxy Xpath :: "Lifting" attributes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I have an XML representing a hierarchical DOM where each element is an `<element ...>` with zero or more children each. Each `<element>` has a ton of attributes and I don't want to litter the `Element` class with all those attributes, given it has a bunch of its own methods too.

The first draft of `Element` class was as follows. This works flawlessly:

```java
class Element {

    @XmlAttribute private String name;
    @XmlAttribute private String bounds;
    // A whole bunch of other attributes
    @XmlElement(name = "element") List<Element> children;
    // A whole bunch of other methods

}
```

I tried to improve this by:

```java
class Element {

    @XmlPath(".") private Attributes attributes;
    @XmlElement(name = "element") List<Element> children;
    // A whole bunch of other methods

}

class Attributes {

    @XmlAttribute private String name;
    @XmlAttribute private String bounds;
    // A whole bunch of other attributes

}
```

This seems to work fine, however, it actually messes up data upon closer inspection. If I input the following XML:

```xml
<element name="Hello" bounds="[0,0][1,1]">
  <element name="World" bounds="[1,1][2,2]">
    <element name="Testing" bounds="[2,2][3,3]">
      <element name="One two three" bounds="[3,3][4,4]" />
    </element>
  </element>
</element>
```

The unmarshalled object has the following structure/properties:

```
+ [Element]
   - name = "World"
   - bounds = "[1,1][2,2]"
   + children[0]
      - name = "Testing"
      - bounds = "[2,2][3,3]"
      + children[0]
        - name = "One two three"
        - bounds = "[3,3][4,4]"
        + children[0]
          - name = "One two three"
          - bounds = "[3,3][4,4]"
          - children = null
```

My assumption was that `XPath(".")` would "lift" the attributes of the `Attributes` class to the parent `Element` class. But in fact it is lifting those attributes two levels upwards.

When I construct the `Element` hierarchy manually, then try to marshall it, the resulting XML is just fine. It is just the unmarshalling that is producing the incorrect object.

Am I using `XPath` incorrectly here? I have a working solution by including all attributes directly within the `Element` class, but I just wanted to group those attributes into a separate class and marshall/unmarshall them to the container `Element` class.

Thanks!
Asim

Comment: Looks like a MOXy bug.

Comment: @Olivier Sure seems like that to me. But I doubt it should be so, given that Moxy has been in the works for so long and surely someone would've stumbled across this long before I did. :(

Answer (score 1):

How about using `@XmlAnyAttribute` with a Map<String,Object>. That should put all attributes that are not accounted for into the map.

```java
class Element {
    @XmlAnyAttribute private Map<String,String> attributes;
    @XmlElement(name = "element") List<Element> children;
}
```

Using it like `element.attributes.get("name)`

Alternatively, you could extend a common `Attributes` class.
These would look in the XML just as if they are in the Element class.

```java
public class Attributes {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String bounds;
}
```

and

```java
class Element extends Attributes {

    @XmlElement(name = "element")
    List<Element> children;
}
```

Comment: You're right that it works, and I am already using it to bunch all unaccounted for attributes in a map. But I lose type-safety this way which is really important to me. So I want to have strongly-typed members that represent the attributes I'm most interested in. :(

Comment: You could also use extension, see my answer above.
But besides that, I don't think it is possible.

Also, I don't know if you actually should separate it, as the separation in two classes is clearly not what the XML actually represents.